# how i can declare the scalar variable

Tags: asp.net, sql

this code was working very well but suddnly its gives me this error message: " Line: 940
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Must declare the scalar variable "@UID"."
Please can anyone help me with this case.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>


<div class="space">
</div>
<div class="space">
</div>
<div class="regepic">
    Registre New User</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table style="width: 69%; height: 338px;" align="center">


   <tr>

   <td class="style5"> &nbsp; Användarnamn</td>
    <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="UsrNme" runat="server" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
   <td>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Userreqlbl" runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="UsrNme" ErrorMessage="This field is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
       <br />
       </td>


   </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Förnamn
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="fnbox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px" 
                ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Efternamn
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="lnamebox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Lösenord
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="passtxtbx1" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="passtxtbx1"
                ErrorMessage="This part is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Återskrivnings Lösenord
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="passtxtbx2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="passtxtbx1"
                ControlToValidate="passtxtbx2" ErrorMessage="The password is not match" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; E-post
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="emailbox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="emailbox"
                ErrorMessage="Invalid Format" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Land
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCOUNTRY" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcecountry" DataTextField="CountID" 
                DataValueField="CountID">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcecountry" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BeravaConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [CountID] FROM [Countries]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Lan
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSTATE" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcestate" DataTextField="Swelan" 
                DataValueField="Swelan">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcestate" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BeravaConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Swelan] FROM [Countries]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Stad
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style11">
            <asp:TextBox ID="citytxtbox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style12">
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Postnummer
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="postbox" runat="server" Width="258px" CausesValidation="True" 
                Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Personlig bild
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="230px" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp;
            </td>
        <td class="style8">

            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click" 
                Text="Enter" style="height: 26px" />



        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
string sc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}


protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
     cn.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string sqlstatment= "INSERT INTO UserInfo (UID, FN, LN, Password, RePass, Email, CountID, State, Post, Img) VALUES (@UID,@FN,@LN,@Password,@RePass,@Email,@CountID,@State,@Post,@Img)";


     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

     cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;
     cmd.Connection = cn;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", fnbox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", lnamebox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passtxtbx1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePass", passtxtbx2.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailbox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountID", DDLCOUNTRY.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", DDLSTATE.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citytxtbox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post",postbox.Text);


     if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
     {

         FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/users/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", FileUpload1.FileName);

     }



     SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
     ad.Fill(ds);
     Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");
}
```

}

Comment: I think you're missing the City variable in your insert statement?

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, yeah i forgot the City but i add it and its same :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you're executing the command *before* adding the parameters values, also the @Img parameter will not be declared if there's no value in the FileUpload control.

To solve this please replace the btnSave_Click method with the following:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

string sqlstatment = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (UID, FN, LN, Password, RePass, Email, CountID, State,City, Post, Img) VALUES (@UID,@FN,@LN,@Password,@RePass,@Email,@CountID,@State,@City,@Post,@Img)";

cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;

//Insert the parameters first
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", fnbox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", lnamebox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passtxtbx1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePass", passtxtbx2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailbox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountID", DDLCOUNTRY.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", DDLSTATE.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citytxtbox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", postbox.Text);

//Check if there's a file or not
if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/users/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", FileUpload1.FileName);
}
else
{
    //Must add the paramater value to any value or DBNull.Value
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", "" );
}

//Open the connection and execute the command
cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Close the connection
cn.Close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank u so much Jack Kokah its work very well now ;-) its working